# How to restrict access to rails_admin admin panel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I have a simple app where i have used devise for authentication. I have just added rails_admin gem

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

This will allow for easy access to data via /admin route. I have also added

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :admin
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_admin)
end
```

to initializer so now authentication is needed before accessing /admin.

But i want one more restriction. I have an admin property in my User model. I change the admin property only via console. I want to restrict access to /admin panel to only Users with admin property set to true.

Currently any user can access the /admin panel provided by rails_admin gem. How can i achieve this goal? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to write this custom authorization since you have a `boolean` field for admin..

```
config.authorize_with do |controller|
  if current_user.nil?
    redirect_to main_app.new_user_session_path, flash: {error: 'Please Login to Continue..'}
  elsif !current_user.admin?
    redirect_to main_app.root_path, flash: {error: 'You are not Admin bro!'}
  end
end
```

Comment: ok thanks this did the trick https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authorization

Comment: Perfect solution, was looking for this,

Comment: @md-farhan-memon added to Rails Admin wiki since it was missing. https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Manually

Comment: Amazing solution! But I belioeve the default devise route is new_user_session_path, not new_account_session_path